# Using built in GPS in windows 8 with precise location?

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad, gps

I have the lenovo helix, with a built 3g chip that features a GPS. So far every map app in the windows store is giving me the wrong location. It is in the same country, but far off. My phone is much more accurate. Why isn't this working properly?

The chip is listed as a geolocation sensor.

Edit: The "my location" in the win8 map metro app gives me some generic geo ip location. Shouldn't the internal GPS take precedence over that?

Comment: are you using the 3g chip to connect to the internet ?

Comment: No, but it is "connected" still. I can try using only that.

Comment: @Shakehar I checked now. Same stuff. A tiny app spits out the exact same long/alt numbers.

Comment: can you check this while not connected to the internet ?

Comment: @Shakehar No, the app did not work when wifi and wwan is off. It just says waiting for an update. Is the gps chip not a "real" one then?

Comment: I guess that your app tapped into the geo-location  of your wi-fi router just like the maps were doing. Try looking for a driver for your sensor by lenovo or the part manufacturer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9804/discussion-between-algific-and-shakehar)